# Create two models at same time with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a potluck where my friends are coming over and will be bringing one or more food items. I have a `friend` model and each `friend` has_many `food_item`s. However I don't want any two friends to bring the same `food_item` so `food_item` has to have a validations of being unique. Also I don't want a `friend` to come (be created) unless they bring a `food_item`.

I figure the best place to conduct all of this will be in the `friend` model. Which looks like this:

```
has_many :food_items
before_create :make_food_item
def make_food_item
    params = { "food_item" => food_item }
    self.food_items.create(params)
end
```

And the only config I have in the `food_item` model is:

```
belongs_to :friend
validates_uniqueness_of :food_item
```

I forsee many problems with this but rails is telling me the following error: `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`

So how do I create two models at the same time with validations being checked so that if the `food_item` isn't unique the error will report properly to the form view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because the Friend model hasn't been created yet since you're inside the before_create callback. Since the Friend model hasn't been created, you can't create the associated FoodItem model. So that's why you're getting the error.

Here are two suggestions of what you can do to achieve what you want:

**1) Use a after_create call back** (I wouldn't suggest this since you can't pass params to callbacks)

Instead of the before_create you can use the after_create callback instead. Here's an example of what you could do:

```
class Friend
  after_create :make_food_item
  def make_food_item
     food_params = # callbacks can't really take parameters so you shouldn't really do this
     food = FoodItem.create food_params
     if food.valid?
        food_items << food
     else
        destroy
     end
  end
end
```

**2) Handle the logic creation in the controller's create route** (probably best option)

In your controller's route do the same check for your food item, and if it's valid (meaning it passed the uniqueness test), then create the Friend model and associate the two. Here is what you might do:

```
def create
  friend_params = params['friend']
  food_params   = params['food']

  food = FoodItem.create food_params
  if food.valid?
    Friend.create(friend_params).food_items << food
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I try your approach I get the error `can't modify frozen Hash`. The reason why I don't want to do this in a controller is because I'm using devise as my login and I don't have easy access to the controllers. However I'm really sick of devise and it's inability to do what I want.

Comment: Yeah. This is impossible to accomplish. I moved the code to the controller but instead of using your method (valid? wasn't a valid method...) I used the `build` function. Something like this: `friend.food_itmes.build(:food => "pineapple")`

Comment: valid? is a built-in method of activerecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html. Can you please post your code? Option #2 should work.

Answer (score 1):

How about to use `nested_attributes_for`?

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_items
  validates :food_items, :presence => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: I don't want to validate if food_item is present. I want to validate if dish in the model of food items is unique.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you'll be be best using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_items, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['foot_item'].blank? }
```

This will create a friend, and not pass the `foot_item` unless one is defined. If you don't want a friend to be created, you should do something like this:

```
#app/models/food_item.rb
Class FootItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :[[attribute]], presence: { message: "Your Friend Needs To Bring Food Items!" }
end
```

On exception, this will not create the friend, and will show the error message instead